# What functions does the brain perform to recognize a familiar object unconsciously?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, vision, neural-network, attention, categorisation

Let's say a person's brain experiences how a vehicle/object looks for the very 1st time. It would require lot of attention/focus/processing to analyse the object, extract features and train its neural networks. After many such experiences (don't know the statistics, does anyone have any clue?), when it sees/experiences the same vehicle/object, it won't need much self/conscious intervention to be able to understand the presence of it. Remember, when driving a car, how many times do we need to actually focus on vehicles/objects? Presumably 0 except for some personal interests (reading number plates, unusual activities) or trigger events that might excite us to do so (turn indicators, possible threats, unusual activities, etc.).

There's also a caveat associated with this behaviour: the brain just knows/believes the vehicle/object exists there with some minimal set of attributes, but it can't read/interpret minute details (like texts/numbers, precise boundaries etc). To do this it requires visual focus as well as the brain's attention, I think.

What brain functions are involved in this activity? What are those features that help the brain perform such tasks without requiring much intervention/processing? Is there any technical term for this behaviour?